# Wear and tear on motors - soft start, also wear impact of sudden power loss?

Tags: motors, stresses

I understand that starting and stopping electric motors puts a lot of strain on them compared to running them continuously.   I suspect that a lot of this strain is due to the sudden inrush of current to start the motor.

I am trying to manage my load (to reduce CO2 emissions and costs by reducing my usage at peak times when power is dirtiest).  I want to do this using IOT switches (like Shelly's or Sonoffs) I have noticed that many of my devices (which are heat pumps/freezers) have soft start on them [ and in the case of my freezer a very long warranty on the compressor ] - on other devices I may be able to add a soft-start if it will help.  (I'm currently running my septic system 24/7 rather then an hourly on-off cycle - because the replacement cost of the motor is very high and the previous 2 did not last that long.  There is definitely no soft start on it, and I'd love to cycle it with a soft start if it won't significantly shorten the life of the unit)

What I have little idea about is the extent to which soft starting mitigates this problem.  Relatedly, I have no idea of the impact of suddenly disconnecting power.   **Can anyone speak to the impact of using soft start and suddenly cutting off power on motors?**

Comment: Who says power is dirtiest at peak times?  During the day is when the sun shines!

Comment: It's easy to get a beefy bearing compared to getting enough coils to apply the force needed.  Damage is generally to conductors.  Arcing on brushes (if any) doesn't help and neither does thermal cycling copper coils in very thin insulation.  Some motors have a fan that does not turn unless the motor spins, meaning normal operation cooling flow is not present at start up.

Comment: @Abel  My power company!  Peak times here are 7am-9am and 5pm to 9pm.  As NZ (where I live) gets most of its power from hydro and geothermal, supposedly the peak load is dirtier as they need to supplement it with gas and coal.

Comment: You are trying to reduce demand when fossil fuels are used (dirty) has nothing to do with motor failure rate or electrical quality with septic pumps. FYI Soft start does not use start/run caps which actually increases demand current to accelerate the motor at 5x full rated motor current.  soft start is often done to minimize starting current by a rising frequency and voltage VCM inverter to provide adequate torque to start with a low frequency. For DC motors a soft start uses a variable PWM rising average voltage.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75T thank you for your comment.  Ill work through it as  much of it went over my head. Reducing demand is when fossil fuels are used is only relevant as it means turning motors on and off more frequently, which I'm fairly sure is more wear.

Answer (score 1):

My experience with industrial motors is about 50% of failures will be due to winding delamination. Eventually it won't pass meggering (resistance tests), and it has to be rewound.  This is directly related to how hard the motor runs and how hot it gets for the hours it runs.  The other 50% is mechanical bearing failure.  Motors in industry tend to run or not and don't really turn on & off a lot.  In home use I would say there is approximately 0% chance you could relate motor failure to installation of real soft-start tech.

I don't know that anyone considered soft starts to be better for motor life.  Good for mechanical components connected to the motor and good for the starter itself.  I guess my home AC might have a starter contactor in there (can't remember ever having to change one), but it's not that big a deal outside of starters that exist in electrical rooms.

Soft starts outside of industry are for if you must remain below a certain amp draw (like using a small generator for power or a fused protection).  The transient nature of starting a motor means that even the high amps of starting aren't going to drive your power bill like just running the thing does (100 amps times 1 sec isn't really very much energy).  People install "soft starts" on their RV's AC units, but I can't imagine it's a good use of resources for residential installs.

Comment: If you are getting 50% bearing fail when run time is accounted for, something is wrong in your bearing and balance considerations.

Comment: @Abel, that would include bearing pre-failure replcement due to vibration.